# PROBLEMATIC CHECKBOX

Tags: javascript, user-interface, checkbox

I have got an array of checkboxes on one of my pages like so:

```
<form name='form1' id='form1'> 
 <table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive'>
 <tbody>
  <tr><th><input type='checkbox' name='year' value='2001' class='form-control' />2001</th></tr>
  <tr><th><input type='checkbox' name='year' value='2002' class='form-control' />2002</th></tr>
  <tr><th><input type='checkbox' name='year' value='2003' class='form-control' />2003</th></tr>
  <tr><th><input type='checkbox' name='year' value='2004' class='form-control' />2004</th></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

I want to use the number of checked boxes to update a div or similar element which displays the number of checked boxes.

My JS looks like :

```
$('#form1 :checkbox').on('change', function(){

    var checked = $('#form1 :checkbox:checked').length;
    console.log( checked );
});
```

The problem is: when any of the boxes is checked, the UI shows it so, but the click/change event is not fired. However, when I click the surrounding, the event is fired  but the UI does not show it. I have spent hours looking at similar questions and applied almost all the suggestions but no headway. Could it be  Any help form house?

Comment: are you trying to say that clicking on label/text change event is not firing ?check this example and  check if this is what your are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/b1okr4zr/ ?

Comment: This could just be me but I have found that on change events with checkboxes are spotty - on click events seem to be MUCH more reliable.

Comment: @AnilNamde, No. I really want to know when my boxes are checked and count how many of them are. But when the checkboxes THEMSELVES are clicked, the events(change or click) are not fired. However, when I click the IMMEDIATE SURROUNDING, the events are fired but the UI of the checkboxes do show 'checked'

Comment: @IfTrue, the change and click events in this case do not make any differences. I have tried both to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: your code seems to be working! http://jsfiddle.net/hyz9motj/ Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Silent_Coder, I thought it ought to work as well. But I am bewildered it is not working. I am using 1.11.2

Comment: @StephenAdelakun Note that you should close the table element by the way - look after you define its class.

Comment: @IfTrue, I copied and pasted line by line. But it is closed in my actual code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Seems like something conflicting, Can you post your code in fiddle and provide the link?

Comment: @Silent_Coder, I cant't believe my eyes. My code worked perfectly in fiddle. The link is https://jsfiddle.net/qg054gto/ . But I noticed I did not get Jquery 1.11.2, so I used 1.11.0. Please take a look and advise me. Should I change from jQuery 1.11.2 ?

Comment: Yes! seems like its an issue with the jQuery 1.11.2 check out this link : https://jsfiddle.net/qg054gto/1/ try upgrading your jQuery library!

Comment: No my bad! Check this revised link https://jsfiddle.net/qg054gto/2/ i think its not an issue with the jQuery.

Comment: Are you using any other javascript library in that page?

Comment: @Silent_Coder, Yeah. Apart from the bootstrap basic, I also use a JS library from the bootstrap template I use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88486/discussion-between-silent-coder-and-stephen-adelakun).

Comment: @Silent_Coder, I later found the problem. I was using an old admin template which refused to work with latest bootstrap. I had to update the said template and that solved the problem. But your instinct saved my situation. When you said "seems like something conflicting" and asked "Are you using other Javascript library ?", I started the investigations that gave me the breakthrough. Thanks dearly.

Comment: @StephenAdelakun I am glad it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Problem is your posted html is invalid, you are missing the `>` for `<table`</strike> Try this example

```js
$(function() {
  var form = $('#form1').on('change', 'input[name=year]', function(e) {
    alert(form.find('input[name=year]:checked').length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name='form1' id='form1'>
  <table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive'>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type='checkbox' name='year' value='2001' class='form-control' />2001</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type='checkbox' name='year' value='2002' class='form-control' />2002</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type='checkbox' name='year' value='2003' class='form-control' />2003</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type='checkbox' name='year' value='2004' class='form-control' />2004</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: No. That is not the problem. In my actual code, the opening table tag is complete. I'll edit to reflect that. Thanks anyway.